# Simple Example to write new Lucene Directory

Tags: lucene

I am looking for a simple example code which helps me write a new Lucene Directory type. Can somebody share an example?

Thx

Comment: What does "_new Lucene Directory type_" mean?

Comment: Also, this isn't really a site where you just ask for code - SO expects some minimal amount of research (and any related coding attempt) to be shown in the question, to help make the question clearer, and to help the community from doing work that you may have already done. We want to help - but can you help us first?

Comment: If we are commenting in lucene forum then Directory in lucene is basic storage where lucene indexes are stored. It is abstract type in lucene

Comment: Maybe this is what you want (I am not sure): Take a look at the Javadoc notes for [`Directory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_2/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) for guidance on how to implement your own class. Take a look at the source code for [`FSDirectory`](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.java) which extends `BaseDirectory` - which, in turn extends `Directory`. For more examples, also look at the source code for `ByteBuffersDirectory` and `FilterDirectory`. So, there you have 3 examples you can study.

Comment: Thx Andrew .. I did look at them and implemented on by myself. It seems I am missing the way the index files are organized. Let me reach out to somebody who is their github contributor